# Javascript don't want to change object value in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need send the objects to api. But I need to change one value of the object in every step of the loop.

```
this.task = {
    RowId: 0
};

var taskWithFid = [];
var fids = [1,2,3,4,5];
var taskTemp = this.task;

fids.map(function(fid){                    
    taskTemp.RowId = fid;
    taskWithFid.push(taskTemp);
}.bind(this));
```

I expect `taskWithFid` array like this:

```
[
    { RowId: 1 },
    { RowId: 2 },
    { RowId: 3 },
    { RowId: 4 },
    { RowId: 5 }
]
```

But I get this:

```
[
    { RowId: 5 },
    { RowId: 5 },
    { RowId: 5 },
    { RowId: 5 },
    { RowId: 5 }
]
```

Can you help me with that?

[Here is the code:](http://plnkr.co/edit/LshCmV544l0Dn7odM3Wb)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as item">

    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1
    <div>{{item.taskWithFid}}</div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format the code fragments. I also included the piece of code from the external site within the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
this.task = {
        RowId: 0
    };
var taskWithFid = [];
var fids = [1,2,3,4,5];
fids.map(function(fid){
 var taskTemp = {};
 taskTemp.RowId = fid;
 taskWithFid.push(taskTemp);
}.bind(this));
```

Move and change `var taskTemp = this.task;` to `var taskTemp = {};`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are pushing the same object into an array, and while doing so you are changing it's RowId. So in the end, when you change it to 5, all will be 5. You need to create separate objects:

```
fids.map (function(fid) {                    
  taskWithFid.push({RowId: fid});
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var taskWithFid = [];
var fids = [1,2,3,4,5];
var taskTemp  
fids.map(function(fid){
this.task = {
        RowId: 0
    };
taskTemp =this.task;                    
 taskTemp.RowId = fid;
 taskWithFid.push(taskTemp);
}.bind(this));
console.log(taskWithFid);
```

Comment: Although this might be a good answer, please consider adding some more explanation about why this is the right solution and what exactly you are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.task` is override each time when you change `RowId`

move your `task` inside `.map` with new variable as `var task { // code }` , so its create new variable each time.

Here is [working flunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u3USFKeyfJTNqqh5GWqv?p=preview)

**fid.map()** should be like :

```
fids.map(function(fid){

    var task = {
        DateCreated: now.toJSON(),
        RowId: 0,
        Subject: null
    };
    task.RowId = fid
    this.taskWithFid.push(task);
    console.log('fid: '+fid);
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the right reason** 
In Javascript objects and arrays are pushed by reference. Objects and arrays not are pushed as copy.

In your code when you are doing following lines you are simply pushing object reference to array.

```
taskTemp.RowId = fid;
taskWithFid.push(taskTemp);
```

At the end the last value is changing all values because of this reference.

**Solution** 
We just need to create a separate object every time we push. Most of the answers are correct here. But still following is my solution:

```
fids.map(function(fid){                    
    this.taskWithFid.push({RowId: fid});
    console.log('fid: '+fid);
}.bind(this));
```